# Is there any event to catch when pop() a screen after back button pressed?

Tags: blackberry

When a button is pressed on Screen A, I push Screen B. And when Back button is pressed on Screen B, I want Screen A to understand that to update Screen. Is there any way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Screen B is popped, it will have its onUiEngineAttached(boolean) function called, with the parameter set to false. If Screen B held a reference to Screen A, it could then trigger whatever updating is needed.

Another way is to setup your own Listener where Screen B would provide the event and Screen A would listen for the event. Again, you would probably fire the event from the onUiEngineAttached(boolean) function.

Comment: Thank you, i will try onUiEngineAttached(boolean) method.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a callback pattern. Check my [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871362/blackberry-select-item-in-a-list-return-to-previous-screen/5872333#5872333) for details. Upon any UI event on your Screen B (e.g. a button is pressed) the Screen B runs the callback passing any parameter if needed. Going this way your Screen A keeps its original/clean interface.

You can detect the device 'Back' btn press with this code:

```
protected boolean keyChar(char c, int status, int time) {
    if (c == Characters.ESCAPE) {
        // .. run callback here ..
        close(); // actually close the Screen B
        return true;
    }
    return super.keyChar(c, status, time);
}
```

Comment: I already use `keyChar()`. And I just passed the reference of Screen A to Screen B and called an update method of A. It works but I don't know if it is a good way to pass the reference.

I don't really know what callbacks do. But I use a ListField and ListCallBack in Screen A. I realize that `drawListRow()` method of ListCallback is called when I press back button from Screen B. So I think a callback will be usefull here. I will look into it, thank you.

Comment: Just to be clear: I am not talking about ListCallBack. This is totally another concept. Passing a reference works Ok, it just creates a too monolithic code, that will be harder to change later.

Comment: Yes, i know it won't be a ListCallBack ofcourse. And I am aware of problems of passing parameter, I will change it.

Answer (score 1):

Screen B is popped off of the stack, so it will get the onUiEngineAttached() callback.  But you are interested in screen A, which will get a different callback - Screen.onExposed().

Comment: Thank you, i will also try this function.

Answer (score -1):

I think this can be done using YUI History manager.