# Creating CUSTOM DROP DOWN in native blackberry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am new in blackberry native programming. I wann create a **Custom Dropdoen** list, I took reference from this link [dropdown list](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Create_a_drop-down_list_509565_11.jsp) but not getting the exact output. My requirment is It should look like the nativ dropdown, with custom look.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out custom drop down list implementation in this thread:
[Issue in PopUpScreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772934/issue-in-popupscreen/9803878#9803878)