# ObjectChoiceField automatically scroll to top after selecting a choice？

Tags: blackberry, java-me, field

I have customized a field which contains an `ObjectChoiceField`. After clicking a choice，the screen just scrolls to the top and the choice field drops down from the visibile screen。Pls tell me how to prevent this。Thank you。

Comment: Post some more details like relevant code, images, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can find out custom drop down list implementation in this thread: [Issue in PopUpScreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772934/issue-in-popupscreen/9803878#9803878)

This custom drop down does what you want.